# Divide variable by column #2 of file1, compare result to file2

Tags: shell

I have two text files.
One contains:

```
Feb,30000
March,40000
April,60000
```

The other contains a value :

```
0.134
```

I want to take numeric input in a variable, and want to divide that number by each of the *1st* file's *2nd* column values, *i.e.*: *30000*, *40000*, *etc*., and want to compare it with the 2nd file's value.

How it will be in script?

Answer (score 1):

As bash doesn't have float number calculation function, you can either use bc or awk.

```
input=10000
value1=$(awk -F [,\ ] '{print $2}' file1)
value2=$(awk '{print $1}' file2)
awk 'BEGIN {if("'$input'"/"'$value1'" > "'$value2'") {print("larger")} else {print("smaller")};}'
```

Comment: awk: BEGIN { if["$input"/"$value1" > "$value2"]
awk:           ^ syntax error
awk: BEGIN { if["$input"/"$value1" > "$value2"]
awk:                                          ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:4: else
awk: cmd. line:4: ^ syntax error

Comment: actually it needs one loop so that it can divide repeatedly. Could you help me with this.

Comment: for eg: when it takes input is dividing with the monday value and comparing with the 2nd file value. again it needs a divide with the tuesday value and so on. How can we do that? please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Some other tool is needed, (*i.e.*: `bc`, `awk`, `calc`, *etc.*), since `bash` lacks floating point.

Let's call the first file *f1*, and the second file *f2*.  First use `sed` and `bash` to write some text expressions:

```
x=4900 ; sed 's#.*,\(.*\)#'$x'/\1>'$(<f2)'#' f1
```

Output:

```
4900/30000>0.134
4900/40000>0.134
4900/60000>0.134
```

From there, feed that expression to `calc` (which will divide, then compare):

```
x=4900 ; sed 's#.*,\(.*\)#'$x'/\1>'$(<f2)'#' f1 | calc -p
```

Output, (in `calc` the *"1"* means *true*, here only *4900/30000* or *0.163...* is greater than *0.134*):

```
1
0
0
```